# Call fragment method when AsyncTask finish on activity

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I have an app with a Navigation Drawer Activity which is calling some fragments on it.

In one of them, I have a Google Map integration, where retrieving from SharedPreferences, I show some markers and stuff.

On the Activity, I have an AsyncTask to update the data when clicking an action bar button. It takes the new data into the SharedPreferences.

I'm having trouble finding a way to call again the paintmap() method from the FragmentMap which is the one that takes the SharedPreferences data and paint the map with the new markers and so on.

I have tried OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener with no result.

Also tried getting the actual fragment with findFragmentByTag but I'm not able to call the method.

So, **what's the better way to tell the fragment that the data has been updated and need to redraw the map?**

Thanks in advance.

**Edit 1: Some things I have tried:**

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);

    txtUpdateInfo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.last_update_info);


    initilizeMap(); // This one includes paintMap at the end. It creates the map.
Check this pastebin for more: http://pastebin.com/DPPB7FiK


    SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener spChanged = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(
                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {

            paintMap();
        }

    };

    return view;
}
```

Also tried, on MainActivity AsyncTask's postExecute, to retrieve the fragment:

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
Fragment f = fm.findFragmentByTag("MAP");

f.paintMap(); // This gives me error and I cannot compile
```

Also, in the same place:

```
 FragmentMap f = new FragmentMap();
 f.paintMap();
```

This last one compiles but gave me NullPointer to everything on the fragment... not working neither.

Comment: **"...I'm not able to call the method."** : Why not? Any `public` method in a `Fragment` can be called directly from the parent `Activity`.

Comment: Have you tried using the onPostExecute method of the AsyncTask to call your refresh functionality?

Comment: show what you have tried

Comment: Edited the post with some of the information. Method is public, and tried to create a new public method in the Fragment, called updateFragment, to call paintMap from it, but no success at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with this code...

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
Fragment f = fm.findFragmentByTag("MAP");

f.paintMap(); // This gives me error and I cannot compile
```

...is that you've declared f as a `Fragment` and the Android `Fragment` class doesn't have a method called `paintMap()`. You need to declare it as `FragmentMap` and cast the return of `findFragmentByTag` as follows...

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
FragmentMap f = (FragmentMap) fm.findFragmentByTag("MAP");
f.paintMap();
```

The call to `f.paintMap()` should work then.

Also (for reference) the following will never work...

```
FragmentMap f = new FragmentMap();
f.paintMap();
```

The reason is that like an `Activity` a `Fragment` has a life-cycle which means it isn't fully initialised until it is used in a `FragmentTransaction` and has gone through its life-cycle methods such as `onAttach`, `onCreateView`, `onResume` etc.